# Fourier Transform in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have found a proof to the following theorem which is a fair bit shorter than the proof in my notes. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me whether this way works or whether I've made an error somewhere. Many thanks.

---

**NOTE:** If $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, define its Fourier transform as follows:

There exists a sequence of Schwartz functions $(f_k)$ such that $\|f-f_k\|_2\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. In particular, the sequence $(f_k)$ is Cauchy and so, by Parseval's identity for Schwartz functions, the sequence $(\,\widehat{f_k}\,)$ of Schwartz functions is also Cauchy and, since $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is complete, it has a limit, say $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. We define this $g$ to be the $L^2$ Fourier transform of $f$ and denote it by $\widetilde{f\,}$.

---

**Theorem.** Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. For each $R>0$ define $f_R \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by 
$$f_R(x) = f(x)\chi_{[-R,R]}(x)$$
where $\chi_{[-R,R]}$ denotes the indicator function of $[-R,R]$. Then
$$\|\widetilde{f\,}-\widehat{f_R}\|_2\to 0 \text{ as } R\to \infty$$
where $\widetilde{f\,}$ denotes the $L^2$-Fourier transform of $f$.

**Proof.** Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given and let $(f_k)$ be a sequence of Schwartz functions such that 
$$\|f-f_k\|_2\to 0 \text{ as } k\to\infty$$
so that, by definition, we have 
$$\|\widetilde{f\,}-\widehat{f_k}\|_2\to 0 \text{ as } k\to\infty$$ 
For any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$\|\widetilde{f\,}-\widehat{f_R}\|_2\leq\|\widetilde{f\,}-\widehat{f_k}\|_2+\|\widehat{f_R}-\widehat{f_k}\|_2$$
But, by Parseval's identity, we have that
$$\|\widehat{f_R}-\widehat{f_k}\|_2=\|f_R-f_k\|_2\leq\|f_R-f\|_2+\|f-f_k\|_2$$
Combining the two inequalities yields
$$\|\widetilde{f\,}-\widehat{f_R}\|_2\leq\|\widetilde{f\,}-\widehat{f_k}\|_2+\|f_R-f\|_2+\|f-f_k\|_2$$
Since this is true for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we choose $k$ so large that
$$\|\widetilde{f\,}-\widehat{f_k}\|_2+\|f-f_k\|_2\leq \varepsilon/2.$$
Clearly, for large enough $R$, we have
$$\|f_R-f\|_2<\varepsilon/2$$
and so, the result follows. Q.E.D.

Comment: You use tildes and hats both for the F. Transform?

Comment: I use tilde for the $L^2$ Fourier transform and hat for the $L^1$ Fourier transform :)

Comment: That's the first time I've seen anyone do that.

Comment: I guess I'm doing it because a corollary of this theorem is that the $L^1$ and $L^2$ Fourier transforms of a function in both $L^1$ and $L^2$ are the same :)

Comment: Actually, it is Parseval's identity for $L^{1}\cap L^{2}$ that gives meaning to the Fourier transform of an $L^{2}$ function as a limit of functions such as $\widehat{\chi_{[-R,R]}f}$. The Fourier transform of an $L^{2}$ function that is not in $L^{1}$ is not directly defined any other way that I've ever seen. So $L^{2}-\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\widehat{\chi_{[-R,R]}f}$ is the basic definition of the $L^{2}$ Fourier transform.

Comment: I have editted my original post to include the definition of $L^2$ Fourier transform that I am using :)

Comment: @user235481 : That's a newer definition, but not improved. You still need $L^{2}\cap L^{1}$ to make sense of the transform as a function, and then a limit in $L^{2}$ to define the final transform, after proving Parseval's identity for $L^{2}\cap L^{1}$.

Comment: Schwartz functions form a (dense) subset of $L^1$

Comment: @user235481 : But you've gained nothing over the classical definition where you simply truncate $f$ to an interval $[-R,R]$ and let $R\rightarrow\infty$. For example, you don't have a pointwise definition, any more than for the classical definition, except through some $L^{2}$ convergent subsequence, which you had for the classical definition.

Comment: I agree with you. But this is the definition I was given to work with... Does the argument I have given work?